# Locally debug a AWS Lambda function within Visual Studio using a sample JSON input string

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I created lambda function and it's hosted AWS using Visual studio AWS SDK. Due to some live issues need to put the break point on this. Somebody suggest to create test project to test that and did the same. After that also it's returning below error.

> AWS lambda in order to debug this project,"Emitentrypoint": true needs
>   to be added to the build options in project.json and an entry point
>   added to your project

After that added emitentrypoint in project.json(Test project)

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "Amazon.Lambda.Core": "1.0.0*",
    "Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents": "1.1.0",
    "Amazon.Lambda.TestUtilities": "1.0.0*",
    "AWSLambda2._0": "1.0.0",
    "xunit": "2.1.0-*",
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-*"
  },
  "testRunner": "xunit",
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

Added entry point in my test class.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    FunctionTest functionTest = new FunctionTest();
    functionTest.TetGetMethod();
}
```

I am new for Test projects.Still I am getting the same issue, give me any suggestion.

Comment: If we want to debug locally, need to use unit test. It's worked for me. Thanks.